# Contact List Web Part in modern pages on a SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, contacts

It's possible create a Contact List Web Part in modern pages on a SharePoint online site? or other method for in my Sharepoint Site my list of contacts be up to date with my contacts in my ad? with my outlook 365?

Comment: There is People webpart in modern SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

There is the old [SiteUsers WebPart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/site-users-web-part-32c2cc3e-b1c7-4eb3-8832-0fc3ab321297). But I'm not sure it's what you are looking for... Also it only works for classic pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can try People web part.

More information:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-people-profiles-on-your-page-with-the-people-web-part-7e52c5f6-2d72-48fa-a9d3-d2750765fa05